# Meteor.http.get request -> Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames

Tags: javascript, http, meteor

I'm trying to use meteor.http module and I'm getting the following error on the server side.
"Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames" since I'm new in Meteor and in Node.js and its javaScript debugging is hard (btw how can I debug server side scripts ? client side it's easy), I'm using MAC OS X 10.9 not sure if it's relevent...

Thanks
Ronen

client side code:

```
'click #buildButton' : function () {
  console.log("Jenkins job request");
  $('#buildButton').attr('disabled','true').val('loading...');
  var userName = "Ronen";
  Meteor.call('jenkinsServiceBuild', function(err, respJson) {
    if(err) {
      window.alert("Error: " + err.reason);
      console.log("error occured on receiving data on server. ", err );
    } else {
      window.alert("Success: ");
      console.log("respJson: ", respJson);
      //window.alert(respJson.length + ' tweets received.');
      Session.set("recentTweets",respJson);
    }
    $('#buildButton').removeAttr('disabled').val('build');
  });
}
```

Server Side Code:

```
Meteor.methods({jenkinsServiceBuild: function(userName) {
  var url = "https://www.ynet.co.il";
  //synchronous GET
  var result = Meteor.http.get(url, {timeout:30000});
  if(result.statusCode==200) {
    var respJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
    console.log("response received.");
    return respJson;
  } else {
    console.log("Response issue: ", result.statusCode);
    var errorJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
    throw new Meteor.Error(result.statusCode, errorJson.error);
  }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site 'https://www.ynet.co.il' has an incorrectly installed SSL certficate for that domain. It's using akamai's certificate.

If you know and trust the site and its for nothing too secure just remove the s in https

```
var url = "http://www.ynet.co.il";
```

Also I'm not sure the code will work, looking at the site it serves html content but this line:

```
var respJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
```

Suggests it serves JSON content. If it does server json content use this instead:

```
var respJson = result.data;
```